# Possible bug of streamslice function or just a misuse of it in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

The problem is simple and very straightforward: I want to plot the magnetic flow of a bar magnet (equal to a solenoid magnetic field), calculated by [these equations](http://nukephysik101.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/finite-length-solenoid-potential-and-field.pdf). My MATLAB version is `R2013a`.

The function that does the job, `magnetic_field` (it returns a struct with the coordinates (r,z) and the field (Br,Bz), **B**(r,z) = Br(r,z)**r** + Bz(r,z)**z** is calculated), is at the end of this question.

I then call

```
>> t = magnetic_field(2e-2, 16e-2, 20, -6e-2, 6e-2, 0.5e-2, -18.2e-2, 18.2e-2, 1e-2);
>> streamslice(t.r, t.z, t.Br, t.Bz)
```

Notice that `t.r` and `t.z` are a `meshgrid` result in which `Br` and `Bz` are calculated (see the `for` loop in the function `magnetic_field`). Thus, all these four matrices have the same `size`.

MATLAB gives the error:

> Attempted to access startgrid(NaN,13); index must be a positive
>   integer or logical.
>
> Error in streamslice>nicestreams (line 324)
>                       startgrid(rr,cc)=1;
>
> Error in streamslice (line 134)
>           [vertsout, avertsout] = nicestreams(x,y,u,v,density,arrows);

The weirdness is: if I change the grid, the streamslice gives no error:

```
>> t = magnetic_field(2e-2, 16e-2, 20, -2, 2, 0.1, -2, 2, 0.1);
```

Although it produces a very strange result (because the solution is only defined for positive `r`, I presume).

I went to check with MATLAB sample data, like the `wind` data:

```
>> w = load('wind');
>> streamslice(w.x(:,:,5), w.y(:,:,5), w.u(:,:,5), w.v(:,:,5))
```

It plots correctly. However, if I change from `5` to either `2`, `3`, `10`, `12` or `15`, MATLAB displays a very similar error to the one I had:

> Attempted to access startgrid(2,0); index must be a positive integer or logical.
>
> Error in streamslice>nicestreams (line 324)
>                      startgrid(rr,cc)=1;
>
> Error in streamslice (line 134)
>          [vertsout, avertsout] = nicestreams(x,y,u,v,density,arrows);

the difference is that with the sample data, the error is that `streamslice` tries to access a `0` index, whilst in my case, it tries to access a `NaN` index.

Thus, I keep with either two possibilities:

1) My data (namely the variables `Br` and `Bz`) do not have the structure required by `streamslice` function
2) it is a bug in the `streamslice` function

What do you think?

Any suggestions?

```
function res = magnetic_field(a, L, I, rMin, rMax, dr, zMin, zMax, dz)    
    Nr = (rMax - rMin) ./ dr + 1;
    Nz = (zMax - zMin) ./ dz + 1;

    % calculating dependent constants
    mu0div2pi = 2e-7;
    Lm1 = 1 / L; % in 1/m
    Ldiv2 = L / 2;
    constZ = Lm1 .* I * mu0div2pi / 4;
    constR = Lm1 .* I * mu0div2pi;

    % defining functions
    kSqr = @(ar4, ar2, zeta) ar4 ./ (ar2 + zeta .^ 2);
    hSqr = @(ar4, ar2) ar4 ./ ar2;
    zetaPlus = @(z, Ldiv2) z + Ldiv2;
    zetaMinus = @(z, Ldiv2) z - Ldiv2;
    IntBr = @(kSqr, eK) ((kSqr - 2) .* eK + 2 .* ellipticE(kSqr)) ./ sqrt(kSqr);
    IntBz = @(kSqr, hSqr, r, zeta, a, eK) zeta .* sqrt(kSqr) .* (eK + ellipticPi(hSqr, kSqr) .* (a - r) ./ (a + r));

    % creating grid
    [r, z] = meshgrid(linspace(rMin, rMax, Nr), linspace(zMin, zMax, Nz));
    [m, n] = size(r);
    NN = m * n;

    Br = zeros(m,n);
    Bz = zeros(m,n);
    for i = 1:NN
        ar4 = 4 .* a .* r(i);
        ar2 = (a + r(i)) .^ 2;
        hh = hSqr(ar4, ar2);
        zP = zetaPlus(z(i), Ldiv2);
        zM = zetaMinus(z(i), Ldiv2);
        kkPlus = kSqr(ar4, ar2, zP);
        kkMinus = kSqr(ar4, ar2, zM);
        eKPlus = ellipticK(kkPlus);
        eKMinus = ellipticK(kkMinus);
        Br(i) = constR .* sqrt(a ./ r(i)) .* (IntBr(kkPlus, eKPlus) - IntBr(kkMinus, eKMinus));
        Bz(i) = constZ .* ( IntBz(kkPlus, hh, r(i), zP, a, eKPlus) - IntBz(kkMinus, hh, r(i), zM, a, eKMinus) ) ./ sqrt(a .* r(i));
    end
    res.a = a;
    res.L = L;
    res.I = I;
    res.r = r;
    res.z = z;
    res.Br = Br;
    res.Bz = Bz;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does seem to be a bug in `streamslice` as @user664303 mentioned, and you should report it.

---

```
w = load('wind');
i = 2;
streamslice(w.x(:,:,i), w.y(:,:,i), w.u(:,:,i), w.v(:,:,i))
```

Working with the `wind` dataset as you instructed (I am using MATLAB R2013b), the error appears to be caused by a round-off error; the value `xc-xmin` unexpectedly returns a very small negative number close to machine precision, which in turn gets turned into `-1` by a call to the `floor` function. This result (incremented by one) is later used for indexing, thus causing the error.

The good news is that I believe there is a simple fix here; replace the call to `floor` by a call to `fix` instead (no pun intended). This should perform *rounding towards zero* instead of *rounding towards negative infinity*, which in the case of positive numbers (which appears to be expected in this context) is equivalent, all the while catching the slight rounding errors that could result in a very small negative numbers when a zero should occur instead and correcting it as such.

I had to perform this change in six different places inside the `streamslice.m` file (simply replace all occurrences of `floor` by `fix`). Here is a patch file of the changes:

```
--- old/streamslice.m
+++ new/streamslice.m
@@ -321,8 +321,8 @@
                     yc = vv(j,2);
-                    cc = floor( (xc-xmin)*ixrangecs )+1;
-                    rr = floor( (yc-ymin)*iyrangers )+1;
+                    cc = fix( (xc-xmin)*ixrangecs )+1;
+                    rr = fix( (yc-ymin)*iyrangers )+1;
                     startgrid(rr,cc)=1;

-                    cc = floor( (xc-xmin)*ixrangece )+1;
-                    rr = floor( (yc-ymin)*iyrangere )+1;
+                    cc = fix( (xc-xmin)*ixrangece )+1;
+                    rr = fix( (yc-ymin)*iyrangere )+1;
                     if endgrid(rr,cc)==1
@@ -336,4 +336,4 @@
                     if arrows
-                        cc = floor( (xc-xmin)*ixrangeca )+1;
-                        rr = floor( (yc-ymin)*iyrangera )+1;
+                        cc = fix( (xc-xmin)*ixrangeca )+1;
+                        rr = fix( (yc-ymin)*iyrangera )+1;
                         if j>1 && arrowgrid(rr,cc)==0
```

Comparing the function between R2013a and R2013b, the files are identical. So I think this workaround should apply to that version as well. Please try it on actual data and see if it works..

---

### EDIT:

As you have discovered, there seems to be a second bug in `streamslice` function. It only affects the code when the data contains NaN values. As far as I can tell, here is the workaround:

```
--- old/streamslice.m
+++ new/streamslice.m
@@ -302,7 +302,7 @@
             for q = 1:2
                 vv = verts{q};

-                nanpos = find(isnan(vv));
+                nanpos = find(any(isnan(vv),2));
                 if ~isempty(nanpos)
                     if nanpos(1)==1
                         vv = [];
```

It is worth noting that generating the data using your function:

```
t = magnetic_field(2e-2, 16e-2, 20, -6e-2, 6e-2, 0.5e-2, -18.2e-2, 18.2e-2, 1e-2);
```

gives different results between R2013a and R2013b (specifically using R2013a, `t.Bz` had a column of all NaN/Inf values not present in the data generated by R2013b)... This explains why the Nan-bug didn't appear in R2013b.

Comment: it works with `wind` data, but fails with my data... I am trying to figure it out now... Thanks for this fix, nevertheless...

Comment: I am dissecting streamslice code, but figuring out what means each variable... The problem with NaN is that near by these lines modified by you (it appears as the first line in your modification log), the variable `vv(j,2)` happens to be NaN... Now, I am trying to check, unsuccessfully, where is `vv` being modified...

Comment: @Girardi: similar to what user664303 reported, I see no errors using your function `magnetic_field` in R2013b, neither before or after the fix I suggested. Only the `wind` dataset gave an error, but that was corrected with the above modifications...

Comment: @Girardi: If you have access to both R2013a and R2013b, try running you function to generate the structure `t` in both versions (using the same parameters) then save them to MAT-files. It would be interesting to compare those two variables and see if something has changing in MATLAB that causes them to be different! As far as I can say, the `streamslice` function itself hasn't changed between the two versions, perhaps one of its dependencies did...

Comment: I just found the bug... Could you share the streamslice.m file from R2013b with me somehow? (if it is allowed by MATLAB policies)... The bug, in R2013a, is a naive `nanpos = find(isnan(vv))` call, whereas it should be `[nanpos, ~] = find(isnan(vv))`, because `size(vv) == [N,2]`, so the linear index returned by the first `find` call is different of the row position of the second `find` call when the `NaN` is in the second column of `vv`

Comment: @Girardi: The code is copyrighted to MathWorks, I think it would be against the license to share it. But that doesn't really matter, I checked and the `streamslice.m` file is exactly identical between R2013a and R2013b (in fact R2012a has also the same code except for minor stylistic edits). Anyway I tried your fix in R2013a, unfortunately it still threw an error.. I think you were right though about it being the source of the problem, so try this instead: `nanpos = find(any(isnan(vv),2));` and report back if it works??

Comment: another source of confusion is that the data generated was different.. My current machine (Win64) has R2013b installed, another (Win32) has R2013a; the data was mostly equal (to within `eps`), but `t.Bz` had a column with Nan/Inf values in R2013a as opposed to all finite numbers in the other. The function `magnetic_field` is pretty complicated, so I don't know where those values are coming from! Here is a text dump of both data I got: [R2013b](http://pastie.org/pastes/8624873/text?key=bulzatg1i5yhx8lcstjq1q), [R2013a](http://pastie.org/pastes/8624872/text?key=xocikhpncfxypjtpxaavq)

Comment: So the nan-bug is really present in both versions, it's just that the data is not recreated exactly the same due to changes in what I guess are the elliptic integral functions from the Symbolic Math Toolbox.. The way I see it there are two separate bugs here: one fixed by replacing all `s/floor/fix/`, the other fixed by using `nanpos = find(any(isnan(vv),2));` instead :)

Comment: you are correct about the source of `inf` and `NaN` in the data: the magnetic field diverges on the surface of the solenoid and at `r,z = 0,0`. Concerning the `nanpos`, it is not enought to look only in the 2nd column of `vv`, because it may contain NaN in either col 1 or 2...

Comment: @Girardi: the problem with that is `nanpos` is used to filter the rows as `vv = vv(1:nanpos(1)-1,:)`, so you want to stop just before the first row that contains a NaN value.. Consider for example `vv = [1,1; 2,nan; nan,3]`. Using `nanpos=find(any(isnan(vv),2))` you will have a `nanpos(1)` of `2`, whereas `[nanpos,~]=find(isnan(vv))` you will get `nanpos(1)` being `3` which is problematic since you still include the Nan that way..

Comment: it is true... I just realized the usability of `any`. I would have to find the minimum of `nanpos` in my proposed solution, what is accomplished by another means with the `any(...,2)` function...

Answer (score 1):

The error using the wind dataset is clearly a bug in streamslice, caused by a poorly handled rounding error. It is present in R2013b. I suggest you report it to TheMathWorks.

The error using your magnetic_field dataset also appears to be a bug in streamslice. I get the same error in R2013a. However, there is no error in R2013b (and the output looks sensible), so it would appear the bug has been fixed in that release.

Comment: I am going to check if I get it fixed with version R2013b. Thanks! =)